# Spring Boot vs. Web server memory consumption

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

If I set into a **web server (Tomcat, Undertow)** an established memory consumption such as -Xms 1024m -Xmx 1024m, the JVM still can increase the memory consumption by factors of buffers, threads and native routines. That means 1024m will not the maximum memory used and I may see into S.O. a process running with much more than that.

With **Spring Boot** applications each jar will have your own web server so in this case if I do not set any -Xms / -Xmx in java execution it will get the default values from JVM in that S.O.

So, my doubt is if I have multiple Spring Boot applications running at the same server, shouldn't I have a bigger memory consumption than just having a single web server with several WAR's inside?

That memory question also applies to CPU and disk usage, **does Spring Boot need more system resources to run?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your post if you are comparing Spring vs non-Spring application but I'll assume it's the case.

Spring [does not have](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-system-requirements.html) particular system resource requirements.
In general when you run a Spring application in a container you can expect a (slightly) higher resource consumption because the framework loads more classes and does some processing that would have been avoided if you did not use Spring at all.

If you consider the Spring Boot case, you'll see that you can run a Spring Boot web application in two ways:

1. via a standalone container
2. [package it as a WAR](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) and run it in your container of choice

In the first case, if there is more than one application, you'll need more resources because there will be multiple containers running (one for each Spring Boot application). In the second case you'll need less because all the applications are consolidated in a single container. This last consideration is more a matter of how you deploy instead of an intrinsic property of Spring or Spring Boot.

Comment: Yes, I am comparing both Spring applications, where the first is packed into a WAR to be deployed in Tomcat and another is running as an standalone Spring Boot application with Tomcat embedded.

Comment: Ok. My post covers both cases

Comment: Yes, but my question is how much resources (cpu / memory) will I need until the server be exhausted? I know that one single container is less than many ones, at the same time we can't think that splitting 1024m could be 10 Spring Boot containers of 100m.

Comment: First it depends on how many resources are available. Then also on the application itself. You cannot answer this question without some profiling. You can start with Java VisualVM and Java Mission Control (both ship with any recent JDK).

Comment: In short, can we think that splitting all the same WAR's into many standalone Spring Boot applications will be heavier than only running in one single Tomcat server?

Comment: Like I said this has nothing to do with Spring Boot. If you run multiple applications on a single tomcat you will have less overhead compared to a situation where you have multiple servers. Remember that Spring Boot applications can be deployed as WARs, not only as standalone ones.